# Identify electric object

Tags: transformer

[image]Can you please help me to identify the red and yellow object in the image I think it's transformer but it doesn't make sense to me in the complete circuit it has five pins two on one side and three on the other [image: strange object]

Comment: Transformer: Yes. Sense? depends on what the circuit does and how you think it works.

Comment: There are different kind of transformers. It could be a transformer or common mode choke. Not all pins may be used if one is for making sure it is mounted the correct way. So unless you show better where in the circuit the component is, there is no guessing what it does and what it is.

Comment: I added a photo of the complete circuit I refered to it as tapped transformer it's connected exactly like that this circuit is a charger and DC motor driver for cheap hair trimmer

Comment: I remembered it's after rectifying diode which made me think it's not a transformer

Comment: Can you include photos of the top and bottom of the PCB, so we can see the rest of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely a small center-tapped transformer.

Hard to tell exactly what type from the picture (as not close enough) but looks like it could be a high-frequency ferrite type, which combined with the circuit makes me think this is a basic non-isolating switching supply.

I understand the question mark over being a transformer given the diode, but the reason that the transformer is still working on "DC" is because the transistor, feedback windings, and RC combination are forming a switching oscillator, which for each positive half-cycle of the mains are switching the current through the transformer primary on and off at a much higher frequency.

Be *very* careful if you are exploring to voltages on that device when it is plugged in, but outside of its case.  There is mains voltage, and contact could lead to a shock or rather exciting arc.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I searched the internet and i found something about flyback transformers but in this circuit there is a short between the primary and secondary what's the purpose of it